# XCode Analyzer : Potential leak of an object

Tags: objective-c, xcode, memory-management, memory-leaks, cocos2d-iphone

here is a piece of code, could you help me managing memory correctly in it please ?

```
- (void) buildSpritesWithName:(NSString*)sN {

    self.arrayPages = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:self.numPages];
    NSString *spriteName0 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%i.png", sN, 0];
    CCSprite *temp0 = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:spriteName0];

    NSLog(@"temp sprite %@ size : %f / %f",spriteName0, temp0.contentSize.width, temp0.contentSize.height);

    self.imgSize = CGSizeMake(temp0.contentSize.width, temp0.contentSize.height);


    for (int c = 1; c <= numberOfWheelFacesCycles; c++) {

        for (int x = 1; x <= self.numPages; x++) {

            NSString *spriteName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%i.png",sN, x];
            CCSprite *temp = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:spriteName];

            [self.arrayPages addObject:temp];
        }
    }

    NSLog(@"%i Pages built",self.arrayPages.count);
}
```

Analyzer says "Potential leak of an object" at line :

```
NSString *spriteName0 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%i.png", sN, 0];
```

Why that ? NSString is autorelease right ? so which object could be leaked ?

I have the following in another class, again, what's the problem :

```
self.name = [playersNames objectAtIndex:type];
```

By the way, if the management of the loop is not good, could you advice as well ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: If you got a correct answer, click the checkmark so we all know it's been answered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at your property or accessor for `arrayPages`. If it retains, then your potential leak arises when you call:

```
self.arrayPages = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:self.numPages];
```

If `arrayPages` retains, then do this instead:

```
self.arrayPages = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:self.numPages] autorelease];
```

or more simply:

```
self.arrayPages = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:self.numPages];
```

As for your loop, it looks all right, but beware of creating a lot of autoreleased objects inside it; they aren't released until some point later.